# New to Python - proficient with Matlab: getting error "IndexError: list index out of range"

Tags: function, loops, for-loop, indexing

As the title says, I'm proficient with Matlab and already have this function written there and it works great. I wanted to learn a new language and I've been pointed to Python so I figured I would write a simple function to get used to the syntax of Python and have something to validate what I've done. I wrote the function "Xfcn" (which is non-dimensional mass flow in rocket problems) and it gives me the correct number if I only use one value. Now, I'd like to plot the X-function versus Mach and validate with my Matlab version. I need to loop through some Mach vector then plot it. Plotting comes later. I'm getting the error mentioned above and I think it's a simple indexing problem, although I can't seem to figure out what it is. I've looked here and on Python's documentation center so hopefully we can resolve this quickly. I've also checked the "type" of "i", printed the range(len(Ms)) and get 0-49, by 1's, as I expect with the particular values of Ms 0-1 by equally spaced increments, also as I expect, so I cannot figure out where my error is. My code is below.

```
from Xfcn import Xfcn
import pylab as pyl
import numpy as np

Ms = np.linspace(0,1,endpoint=True)
X = []
for i in range(len(Ms)):
    X[i][0] = Xfcn(Ms[i])
print X
print 'Done.'
```

Thanks for the help!
BL

Answer (score 0):

You created x as a single dimensional list and are trying to access it as if it was multi dimensional